# ¿Como puedo dividir un String en diferentes partes?

Tags: c++

estoy realizando una funcion que al pazar un string en el siguiente formato

```
1413215587 MAYORGA PEREZ CAMILO ESTEBAN
```

lo divida en 5 partes

1. Documento
2. Primer Apellido
3. Segundo Apellido
4. Primer Nombre
5. Segundo Nombre

No tengo experiencia manejando `strings` ni `char` entonces mi codigo es algo tosco o rudimentario y quisiera mejorarlo usando vector y string pero no me funciona, el caso es que   mi codigo compila bien pero cuando voy a ejecutarlo copio el string de ejemplo, lo pego funciona pero me devuelve `(program exited with code: -1073741819)` como se muestra en la siguiente imagen, y creo que es un error de buffer overflow pero no estoy seguro, el caso es que quiero que me retorne `return 0`, intente ver si era un error en la variable que sirve como puntero y funciona bien, pero cuando imprimi la variable i hay me devuelve return 0, pero no quiero que me imprima ningun dato.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
 string s;
  getline(cin, s);

    char documento[50]; // es 11 porque es necesario agregar espacio para el caracter de terminacion '\0' 
    char primer_apellido[50];
    char segundo_apellido[50];
    char primer_nombre[50];
    char segundo_nombre[50];

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int espacios = 0;

    while(s[i] != '\0'){

        if (s[i] == ' '){ espacios++; }
        i++;

     }
     
     i = 0;

    if (espacios == 4){

        while(s[i] != ' '){ documento[j++] = s[i++]; }

         documento[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         

         while(s[i] != ' '){ primer_apellido[j++] = s[i++]; }

         primer_apellido[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         
         while(s[i] != ' '){ segundo_apellido[j++] = s[i++]; }

         segundo_apellido[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;        

         while(s[i] != ' '){ primer_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }
     
         primer_nombre[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         
         while(s[i] != ' '){ segundo_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }

         segundo_nombre[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i = 0;
         
     }
    
    cout<<"documento:"<<documento<<'\n';
    cout<<"primer_apellido:"<<primer_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<"segundo_apellido:"<<segundo_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<"primer_nombre:"<<primer_nombre<<'\n';
    cout<<"segundo_nombre:"<<segundo_nombre<<'\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

[image: Error Return]

Comment: Creo que el ultimo while debe ser:  while(s[i] != '\0'){ segundo_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; } y no  while(s[i] != ' '){ segundo_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }, porque hay cuatro espacio, y tu busca 5, y ¿tambien, que les pasa a los cout cuando le introduces menos de 4 espacios?

Comment: @DanielBriceño no puedo poner ningun menjase debido a que es una funcion que voy a llamar miles de veces.

Comment: Entiendo, Una sugerencia: ¿Porque no usas estructura para encapsular todos los char[50]?

Comment: @DanielBriceño, pero el struct no deberia usarlo cuando son diferentes tipos de datos ?, osea ¿que ventaja me da ?

Comment: Nada importante solo te permite encapsular un poco los datos: struct Datos{char documento[50];
    char primer_apellido[50];
    char segundo_apellido[50];
    char primer_nombre[50];
    char segundo_nombre[50];}

Comment: cuando trabajes con multiples lineas en lugar de hacer char documento[CANTIDAD QUE NECESITAS][50]; con todos los datos, puedas hacer: struct Datos datos[Cantidad que necesitas]; y esto te permitirá hacer  while(s[i]!=' '){datos[i_d].primer_nombre[j++]=s[i++]} en lugar de primer_nombre[i_d][j++]=s[i++];

Comment: @DanielBriceño gracias no lo sabia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es simple de solucionar solo debes cambiar el chat comparado por el ultimo while de ' ' a '\0', porque tu programa busca 5 espacio, pero tu le pasa 4:

```
1413215587 MAYORGA PEREZ CAMILO ESTEBAN
          1       2     3      4
```

Como solo hay cuatro no nos sirve para establecer un limite a la ultima palabra, asi que usamos el carácter que marca el final de la cadena '\0':
Linea cambiada: `while(s[i] != '\0'){ segundo_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
 string s;
  getline(cin, s);

    char documento[50]; // es 11 porque es necesario agregar espacio para el caracter de terminacion '\0' 
    char primer_apellido[50];
    char segundo_apellido[50];
    char primer_nombre[50];
    char segundo_nombre[50];

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;

    int espacios = 0;

    while(s[i] != '\0'){

        if (s[i] == ' '){ espacios++; }
        i++;

     }
     
     i = 0;

    if (espacios == 4){

        while(s[i] != ' '){ documento[j++] = s[i++]; }

         documento[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         

         while(s[i] != ' '){ primer_apellido[j++] = s[i++]; }

         primer_apellido[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         
         while(s[i] != ' '){ segundo_apellido[j++] = s[i++]; }

         segundo_apellido[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;        

         while(s[i] != ' '){ primer_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }
     
         primer_nombre[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i++;
         
         while(s[i] != '\0'){ segundo_nombre[j++] = s[i++]; }

         segundo_nombre[j] = '\0';
         j = 0;
         i = 0;
         
     }
    
    cout<<"documento:"<<documento<<'\n';
    cout<<"primer_apellido:"<<primer_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<"segundo_apellido:"<<segundo_apellido<<'\n';
    cout<<"primer_nombre:"<<primer_nombre<<'\n';
    cout<<"segundo_nombre:"<<segundo_nombre<<'\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

La clase `std::string` de la librería estándar `<string>` tiene funciones que pueden ayudar con el problema. En casos como este es mejor usar `std::string` en lugar de un array de char. [Documentación de `std::string` (en inglés)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Quizá no sea la solución mas eficiente, pero resuelve el problema:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    string documento; // es 11 porque es necesario agregar espacio para el caracter de terminacion '\0' 
    string primer_apellido;
    string segundo_apellido;
    string primer_nombre;
    string segundo_nombre;

    documento = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '));
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    primer_apellido = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '));
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    segundo_apellido = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '));
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    primer_nombre = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '));
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_of(' ') + 1);

    segundo_nombre = s;

    cout << "documento:" << documento << '\n';
    cout << "primer_apellido:" << primer_apellido << '\n';
    cout << "segundo_apellido:" << segundo_apellido << '\n';
    cout << "primer_nombre:" << primer_nombre << '\n';
    cout << "segundo_nombre:" << segundo_nombre << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿gracias, sabes como podria hacer el otro igual pero con strings ?, lo intento y no me funciona

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo no entiendo a que te refieres con _hacer el otro igual pero con strings_.

Comment: osea cambiar las variables del codigo que hice pero con strings

Comment: @GregorioVaronRengifo para reemplazar los `char [50]` por `std::string` tienes que cambiar los `'\0'`, ya que a diferencia de un array, `std::string` no termina en null. Por otro lado, `std::string` esta hecho para ser usado junto a sus funciones, ofreciendo mayor versatilidad que un array de `char`, por lo que no tiene sentido usarlo si vas a trabajarlo como array. De hecho en C++ moderno el array no se usa mucho, este se suele reemplazar por `std::array` (versión "moderna" del array), `std::vector` (array con tamaño dinámico), `std::string`, etc.

Comment: gracias, no sabia